# SAS: create new variables from array

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with 20 variables that all start with `date_`, that represent the date of a particular procedure. I wish to use an arrays and `do` to create 20 new variables that have the same name, except the `date_` is replaced with `time_`, and is equal to the number of days between the `date_` variable and some reference date `ref_date`.

So far, I can perform the very simple operation to replace each element:

```
data morbidity;
    set morbidity;

    array dates date_:;

    do over dates;
        dates =  dates - ref_date;
    end;
    format date_: 11.;
run;
```

But I can't figure out how to specify a new array `times` with the same suffix as `dates`:

```
data morbidity;
    set morbidity;

    array dates date_:;
    array times /* Some array here */

    do over dates;
        times=  dates - ref_date;
    end;
run;
```

So, take for example `date_amputation`, I wish to create `time_amputation` which is equal to the difference between `date_amputation` and `ref_date`.

Comment: What are the actual names of the DATE variables?  What names do you want to give to the new TIME variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know how many variables you want to create.

So code like this will work for up to 20 new variables.  If you do not list the variable names in the ARRAY statement then they will be named TIMES1 to TIMES20.

```
data morbidity;
    set morbidity;

    array dates date_:;
    array times [20] ;

    do index=1 to min(dim(dates),dim(times);
       times[index]=  dates[index] - ref_date;
    end;
    drop index;
run;
```

If you want the new variable names to be based on the old variable names then you will need to use some code generation.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select name,'time'||substr(name,5)
    into :dates separated by ' '
       , :times separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='WORK' and memname='MORBIDITY'
      and upcase(name) like 'DATE^_%' escape '^'
   ;
quit

data morbidity;
    set morbidity;

    array dates &dates;
    array times &times;

    do index=1 to dim(dates);
       times[index]=  dates[index] - ref_date;
    end;
    drop index;
run;
```